# Ensuring the latest SQL record is always chosen for a calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactions, batch-processing

We have a financial log of transactions made by our customers stored in a database table, the table includes information on:

- Transaction ID
- Customer ID
- Date/time of transaction
- Amount
- Balance

The balance of a new transaction is calculated by taking the latest, previous transaction (using date/time of a transaction) with the same customer ID and summing this with the amount of the new transaction.

As this is a transaction log, none of the details can be modified by a user.

We are using SQL Server's GETDATE to derive the customer's current balance. Is this sufficient to ensure we are always choosing the customer's latest transaction to do the balance calculation? Important for us to do this since if we pick the incorrect transaction, the customers' transaction log would not add up.

Example of what the table could look like (an image since it doesn't look like I can use markdown to create the table):

[image: Example table of transaction logs]

Our system also has screens to do bulk add of transactions, here we insert the transactions as a SQL batch. Are these any possibilities here where two or more transactions entered for a customer could have same date/time and therefore cause problems with our balance calculations for subsequent transactions?

Comment: Why *store* the balance at all? Balance can always be correctly calculated by summing the history of all transactions, and that is the actual accurate data.

Comment: `DateTime` (and as a result, `GetDate()`) is only accurate to 3 milliseconds. You should use `DateTime2` (and `SysDateTime()`) instead, since it's maximum accuracy is 100ns

Comment: Sample data and expected output?

Comment: To expand on @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment, if you add an index on Customer ID, and add Amount as an included column, this would be really fast to lookup the balance with a sum, rather than keep a running sum column. I can understand it may be convenient having that column for reporting, but not for data consistency the way your're using it. Is there any specific reason you went for this design?

Comment: I have no idea what business you are in. What I know of banking system - Based on date time is not enough to calculate balance. By adding batch id plus sequence are still not sufficient to calculate balance. It combines many business rules to deal with various situations to calculate balance.

Comment: @Wendy I'm not working in banking, but out of curiosity what are some examples of these business rules that are used to calculate balance? Some insight may help with tackling this problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever By not storing the balance, performance of the calculation overtime concerns me the most. We are not clearing down any historical data and so calculating on the fly may hamper the performance in the long run. Probably a lesser issue if this is just calculating for one customer at a time, but we also reporting available where it's possible to pull the current balance of selected number of customers.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Updated with an example of what the table should look like.

Comment: There are many types of balance, current balance, statement balance, available balance, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of problem, my starting point is always to try to create a table structure that *cannot store wrong data*. With that as the starting point, you then can add additional structures around it to try to make it more useful.

So, *if* we've decided having a running total around is a good idea (I'd usually advise against this, as indicated in the comments, and just compute it on demand), we need to create a table structure that promotes this:

```
create table dbo._Ledger (
    CustomerID int not null,
    TransactionID int not null,
    OccurredAt datetime2 not null,
    TransactionAmount decimal(22,5) not null,
    PreviousTransactionID as CASE WHEN TransactionID > 1
                                  THEN TransactionID - 1 END persisted,
    PreviousBalance decimal(22,5) null,
    Balance as CONVERT(decimal(22,5),
                      ISNULL(PreviousBalance,0.0) + TransactionAmount) persisted,
    constraint PK_Ledger PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID,TransactionID),
    constraint CK_Ledger_IDs CHECK (TransactionID > 0),
    constraint CK_Ledger_Continuous CHECK (TransactionID=1 and PreviousBalance is null or
                                       TransactionID > 1 and PreviousBalance is not null),
    constraint UQ_Ledger_XRef UNIQUE (CustomerID,TransactionID,Balance),
    constraint FK_Ledger_XRef
        FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID,PreviousTransactionID,PreviousBalance)
        references dbo._Ledger(CustomerID,TransactionID,Balance)
)
```

With the above structure, what we have is a table that builds up a ledger for each customer. The `Balance` column is a computed column - computed by adding the transaction amount to the previous balance. And we ensure that the previous balance is correct by making it part of a foreign key that references the previous row(`UQ_Ledger_XRef` and `FK_Ledger_XRef`).

We also have some check constraints that ensure that the history we build up is unique and unambiguous - every customers transactions must be numbered from `1` upwards, with no gaps.

Having created that structure, though, we find its considerably more complex than what we wanted to expose to the users - so we create a view:

```
create view dbo.Ledger
with schemabinding
as
    select
        CustomerID,
        ISNULL(TransactionID,0) as TransactionID,
        OccurredAt,
        TransactionAmount,
        Balance
    from
        dbo._Ledger
```

This now just shows the columns that the users will care about and hides the complexity from them. When users insert into this view, they'll just populate `CustomerID`, `OccurredAt` and `TransactionAmount` - the other columns (`TransactionID` and `Balance`) are computed.

However, insertion into this view is not straightforward, so we also need to supply a trigger:

```
create trigger Ledger_I
on dbo.Ledger
instead of insert
as
    ;With Ordered as (
        select
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID order by OccurredAt) as rn,
            SUM(TransactionAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID
                                         order by OccurredAt
                                         rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
             - TransactionAmount as Running
        from
            inserted
    ), Historic as (
        select
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID Order by TransactionID desc) as rn
        from
            dbo._Ledger
        where
            CustomerID in (select CustomerID from inserted)
    )
    insert into dbo._Ledger 
    (CustomerID,TransactionID,OccurredAt,TransactionAmount,PreviousBalance)
    select o.CustomerID,
           o.rn + COALESCE(h.TransactionID,0),
           o.OccurredAt,o.TransactionAmount,
        CASE WHEN o.rn > 1 or h.Balance is not null THEN h.Balance + o.Running END
    from
        Ordered o
            left join
        Historic h
            on
                o.CustomerID = h.CustomerID and
                h.rn = 1
```

And hopefully you can see how the common table expressions are working together to assign correct `TransactionID`s and populate the correct `PreviousBalance` amounts.

(By the way, the `_` prefix on the table is just my convention for objects which I don't intend for users to access directly. There's no specific significance to it)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can query as below windowing function:

```
Select *, Balance = sum(Amount) over( partition by CustomerId order by TransactionDate) 
    from #Transaction
```